# What does "CATs three and four" mean?

Tags: military, terminology, aircraft-carrier

I heard this line *in Top Gun* (1986) film:

> Airboss: Ready Willard and Simkin off **CATs three and four**.

What does "CATs three and four" mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CATs three and four refer to an aircraft carrier's **Catapults** (number 3 and 4 in your question) used for launching/catapulting aircraft off the flight deck (in addition to the aircraft's own engine thrust/power).

Comment: [here's an unofficial site showing the locations of the four catapults](https://www.navysite.de/cvn/flightdeck.htm)

Comment: And in case tedder42's link goes down: 1-4 in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZTKK.png)

Comment: Another more readable image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0EEQ.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Like the other poster suggested, ‘CAT’ being short for aircraft catapult.  This is a reference to catapults number three and four, sometimes called the ‘waist’ catapults or waist cats marked in red below.

[image]